# git svn clone results in empty directory

Tags: git, svn

I have an svn repository with project structure:

```
/root/projectA/trunk
/root/projectA/branches
/root/projectA/tags

/root/projectB/trunk
/root/projectB/branches
/root/projectB/tags
```

I want to clone projectA.  When I run:

```
git svn clone -r <revision number>:HEAD <url>/root/projectA
```

I get no errors and a git repository is created under the new projectA directory.  However the directory is empty.  Am I missing soemthing?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318278/git-svn-clone-command-executes-without-errors-but-the-local-master-branch-is-mis

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Below command did the job:

```
  git svn clone -r HEAD <url>/root/projectA
```

Answer (score 68):

My problem was using the `-s` or `--stdlayout` because my svn repo did NOT have a standard layout (trunk, branches, tags).

Comment: Same here.  I had a single repo with a bunch of projects, each with trunk, tags, and branches -- but that is NOT standard layout.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone including the `authors-file` option, `git svn clone` will **stop completely** if it encounters an author without a lookup value in the supplied authors file. If you're not paying attention, git's "alert" for this may look like the repo has finished cloning, and doesn't state that the process is not complete. The repo's directory will be empty, besides .git.

If you add the missing author, then rerun the **exact** command, git will continue where it halted.

Comment: How can you find out which author is missing?

Comment: @LovesTha, the missing author will be output on the screen.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, and it was very confusing.  I had a "mostly" standard layout, but some random dirs in root as well - I assumed this, or perhaps the old version of subversion was the problem when in fact it was the problem with missing authors. I had intentionally deleted some authors that I didn't want to rewrite, assuming it was optional and not realizing the last warning on the screen was really a fatal error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and it was solved by using the --no-metadata argument. In your case, this would amount to

```
git svn clone -r <revision number>:HEAD <url>/root/projectA --no-metadata
```

Comment: Please see the pros and cons of using no-metadata from the link - http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn before using this option.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the HTTP or HTTPS transports (i.e. your repository URLs start with HTTP[s]), you need to provide a valid **SVN** username.

```
git svn clone -s https://svn.example.com/root/projectA --username <SVN username>
```

*-s is an alias for --stdlayout*

However, I only had to specify the --username option once and subsequent calls worked without it. I guess it caches the username.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, executing 'git reset --hard HEAD' in the directory seemed to create the files.

.git/objects was quite large, so I guess the files were imported from svn into git, they just weren't checked out, or something.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the clone operation wasn't completing properly. `git svn clone` would fail partway through the checkout.  Once I fixed the issue, it automatically did the checkout after the clone operation--no more empty folder.

[Update]
Here's what worked in my case:

Attempting `git svn clone --preserve-empty-dirs <repo>` failed for me.  After scouring the net, I found https://www.semitwist.com/articles/article/view/the-better-svn-git-guide, which says, in part:

> This part is a bit of an annoyance. From v1.7.7 onward, Git has a --preserve-empty-dirs. Problem is, the damn thing's broken. If you try to use it as-is, the whole operation will likely just fail partway through. It has to be fixed.
>
> First, find your git-svn file:
>
> $ find / 2> /dev/null | grep git-svn
>
> $ find 2>/dev/null / -type f | grep -l "Failed to strip"
>
> For me, it was at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn.

Note: It’s not in git-svn any more (at least not in git 2.7.0).  I found it in `/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/Git/SVN/Fetcher.pm`.

Open the target file in your favorite editor:

`sudo <your-favorite-editor> path/to/file`

> Now, in this git-svn file, search for `die "Failed to strip path`. ([Depending on your version of git,] it [may] be somewhere near line 4583. Change the `die` to `print` and save. Your git-svn is now fixed.

`git svn clone --preserve-empty-dirs <repo>` should now behave as expected.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Sorry, @DDivita.  I'm not sure why I didn't put the solution I found in my reply.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I could not chech whether this is working, but try:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout <url>/root/projectA/
```

Comment: No difference. still end up with an empty directory!